# Force 301 redirect with trailing slash at the end of urls

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

website recently change the urls from `mywebsite.com/cat1` to `mywebsite.com/cat1/` (notice the trailing slash at the end of the url).

In order to update search engines, I want to 301 redirects the old urls to the new ones.

I was able to make the redirect works on URLs which do not contain variables, however I cannot make it works on URLs which contain parameters.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /profiles/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /tags/?$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]


# Orginal URL Rewrite

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /profiles/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . models.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /tags/hash-([a-z\-A-Z]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . ?tag=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z\-A-Z]+)-profile/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . ?model=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z\-A-Z]+)-profile/([a-z\-A-Z]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . m.php?model_url=%1&media_url=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /tags/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . tags.php [L]
```

any help ?

Comment: By "variables", do you mean URL parameters in query strings? Your "Force trailing slash" directives only work for single path segment URL-paths - is that intentional? However, none of the directives you've posted would seem to work on a URL of the form `/cat1` ?

Comment: URL parameters yes, /cat1 was an expample